# Firestore: The operation was aborted, typically due to a concurrency issue like transaction aborts, etc. (firestore/aborted)

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Code was running fine on simulator when suddenly:

--> Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation`s execution. (firestore/failed-precondition).

Then I installed the app on the physical device(android) and then:

--> Firestore: The operation was aborted, typically due to a concurrency issue like transaction aborts, etc. (firestore/aborted)

```
async setModal() {
    await this.setState({ showCardDetails: false });

    const { userCard, following } = this.props;

    let userKey = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserKey');
    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserDetails');
    console.log(userCard.key);
    const currentUserID = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userKey);

    const id = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userCard.key);

    firebase.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {

      //If follows the user
      if (following) {
        //Update the following of the viewing user
        if (userCard.followers) {
          let result = await userCard.followers.find(f => f === userKey);
          if (!result) {
            let foll = userCard.followers;
            foll.push(userKey);
            transaction.update(id, {
              followers: foll
            });
          }
        } else {
          let foll = [];
          foll.push(userKey);
          transaction.update(id, {
            followers: foll
          });
        }

        //Update the following of the loggedIn user
        if (user.following) {
          let result1 = await user.following.find(f => f === userCard.key);
          if (!result1) {
            let folln = user.following;
            folln.push(userCard.key);
            transaction.update(currentUserID, {
              following: folln
            });
          }
        } else {
          let folln = [];
          folln.push(userCard.key);
          transaction.update(currentUserID, {
            following: folln
          });
        }
        //If unfollows the user
      } else if (!following) {
        //Update the following of the viewing user
        if (userCard.followers) {
          let result = await userCard.followers.find(f => f === userKey);
          if (result) {
            let result2 = userCard.followers.filter(f => f !== userKey);
            transaction.update(id, {
              followers: result2
            });
          }
        }

        //Update the following of the loggedIn user
        if (user.following) {
          let result1 = await user.following.find(f => f === userCard.key);
          if (result1) {
            let result2 = user.following.filter(f => f !== userCard.key);
            transaction.update(currentUserID, {
              following: result2
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

At the start of the signup, the document is added fine, but these transactions are not running properly.

"react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
 "react": "16.8.3",
 "react-native": "0.59.3",